# Java 8 stream map reusing assigned variable

Tags: java, filter, mapping, java-8, java-stream

I'm aware that title may be a little confusing but I couldn't come up with a better one so let me explain what I mean...

I have this piece of code:

```
int spacing = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (Edge edge : edges) {
    if (!union.connected(edge.getStart(), edge.getEnd())) {
        spacing = Math.min(spacing, edge.getWeight());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to turn this code into java 8 code?

Of course, first step is filtering which is simple, but then it becomes tricker because I would have to reuse computed variable `spacing` in Stream::map method and I have no idea is that possible.

Comment: Note that your code is `java-8` compatible.

Comment: Of course it is... It's java 7.... But I would like to write it in java 8 style

Comment: You should clarify that. You want to use Java 8's lambdas and functional style.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear actually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the syntax (I can't test it), but it should work with something like this :

```
int spacing = edges.stream()
                   .filter(edge -> !union.connected(edge.getStart(), edge.getEnd()))
                   .min (Collectors.comparing(Edge::getWeight))
                   .map (Edge::getWeight) // get the weight of the min Edge
                   .orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Not sure about the Comparator passed to `min`.

In case the code above doesn't work, you can `mapToInt` first (assuming `getWeight()` returns int) :

```
int spacing = edges.stream()
                   .filter(edge -> !union.connected(edge.getStart(), edge.getEnd()))
                   .mapToInt(Edge::getWeight)
                   .min ()
                   .orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Only "mistake" you made is that `min` returns `Optional` so you need to extract actual result out from it... As general solution it's perfect... ty (can't vote up because of poor reputation as new user)